# DOM library for <canvas>

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I understand the differences between `<canvas>` and SVG, and the pros and cons of both. I'm creating a hierarchical diagram, whose nodes and connections a user can manipulate through event handling. The clear winner would normally be SVG, as there's a true DOM I can use.

However, I've heard claims that `<canvas>` is a contender for such an application with the proper scene graph (DOM) library. I can't find consensus on what the go-to scene graph library for `<canvas>` is (for SVG, it's [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)). Can someone point me in the right direction, or are these libraries too immature to supersede SVG for complex DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cake](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/) ([old page](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake)) is a library for that. I've used it and it worked quite well.

Comment: I'm wary of the warning on the front page: "Sadly, I can't summon the effort needed to keep this thing up-to-date and get the bugs fixed. So I'm looking for a maintainer, email me if you want to take over!"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might like to check out [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) (still SVG-based, but does allow large datasets and has good performance).

Comment: That's an interesting library but doesn't provide the sort of DOM object for `<canvas>` that I'm looking for.